# A more pythonic way to check for duplicate characters and check that they are next to each other?

Tags: python

Is there a more pythonic way to check if there are two '((' AND '))' in the string? I've made an attempt but it does not look very pythonic

```
def check (string):

    text = list(string) 

    prev = text[0]
    curr = text[1]
    first=False
    second=False

    for nxt in text[2:]:    
        if (prev == "(" and curr == "("):
            first = True

        elif (curr == "(" and nxt == "("):
            first = True

        elif (prev == ")" and curr == ")"):
            second = True
        
        elif (curr == ")" and nxt == ")"):
            second = True
        
        prev = curr
        curr = nxt
       
    if (first == True and second == True):
         return "true"
    else:
        return "false"
```

examples:

```
check("((a)) + b") # true
check("((a) + b") # false
check("(a+b))") # false
check("((a+b))") # true
check("((a)(b))") # true
check("(((a)))") # true
check("a)) + ((b") # true
```

Comment: Hi @Ceiun, are you trying to parenthesis match for pairs `>= 2`?

Comment: I think regex will be the easiest.

Comment: For starters, `text = list(string)` totally pointless

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a string has *balanced parentheses?*

Comment: Also, generally returning the strings `"true"` and `"false"` instead of booleans is not a great design choice, I'm assuming this is some requirement of whatever coding site you are using, but just know for the future

Comment: Hi @Urmzd, yes the code should return true if there's >=2 pairs of both '(' and '')' anywhere within the string

Comment: What about something like this `((_)(_))` or `(((_)))`?

Comment: @PM77-1 those should also return true

Comment: What about `))((`?

Comment: @KellyBundy that should return True as well as they are both present in the string. The order in which they're presented shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is "has adjacent parens of each type", the solution is just:

```
def check(string):
    return '((' in string and '))' in string
```

A regex could be used to confirm they appear in the correct order and reduce the work to a single pass over `string`, not two, but if you don't need correct "logical" order, the incremental work of scanning twice is pretty meaningless 99% of the time. A regex solution would just be:

```
import re

def check(string):
    return re.search(r'\(\(.*\)\)', string, re.DOTALL) is not None
```

Comment: Side-note: Returning `"true"` and `"false"` is an abomination, so both functions return `True` and `False` (the actual constants representing boolean truth). The caller can convert to appropriate strings if they need to.

Comment: Another: `0 <= string.find('((') < string.rfind('))')`

Comment: Another: `string.find('))', string.find('((')) > 0`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: The latter does have the advantage of limiting yourself to a single scan. I'm just a little leery of `.find` (in this case I think it's safe, but there are too many cases where the `return -1` on failure leads to silent misbehavior). In the real world, I'd probably use `try`/`except ValueError:` with `str.index` for `'(('`, with an `else` case that used the result of the first `index` to limit the scope of the second `index` call, with any exception leading to `return False`, and a lack of exceptions `return True`. It's more verbose, but removes my worries about `str.find`. :-)

Comment: Yes, that one is admittedly somewhat tricky and brittle. For example if it was about single parentheses, `string.find(')', string.find('(')) > 0` wouldn't work right.